# Opening file to read in C++, issue with filename string

Tags: c++, linux, ifstream

I'm opening a file to read in C++ (Linux, Debian).

```
ifstream input ("readme");
```

The above works, but when I try:

```
string filename = "readme";
ifstream input (filename);
```

I get a page load of errors starting with `error: no matching function for call to...`

Why doesn't this work and how can I use a string variable as file name input?

Answer (score 4):

You can use :

```
string filename = "readme";
/* Convert filename to C string of type const char* 
 (null terminated) using c_str method
*/
ifstream input (filename.c_str());
```

Or use C++11 flag

`-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x`

Ref: [`c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of `ifstream` and friends accepting an `std::string` has only been added in C++11, which means you should use a C++11 conforming standard library implementation, or at least one that support the specific feature. [See cppreference for additional info.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream)

To be able to use an `std::string` as the filename in your case, use [`std::string::c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str):

```
string filename = "readme";
ifstream input (filename.c_str());
```

This method works for older, non-C++11 compilers.